# How to find depent source files of one target automatically in CMake

Tags: cmake

I have some files in my project, this is the structure:

- main.cpp
- addition.cpp
- division.cpp
- print_result.cpp

I write a CMakeLists like below and it can work well:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Calculator_Project VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(calculator
main.cpp 
addition.cpp
division.cpp
print_result.cpp)
```

or

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(Calculator_Project VERSION 1.0.0)

add_library(my_math addition.cpp division.cpp)
add_library(my_print print_result.cpp)

add_executable(calculator main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(calculator my_math my_print)
```

However, if I want to add more modules such as multiplication or subtraction... I have to add these modules to the CMakeLists.txt as below, it looks not well.

```
add_executable(calculator
main.cpp 
addition.cpp
division.cpp
multiplication.cpp
subtraction.cpp 
print_result.cpp)
```

or

```
add_library(my_math  
addition.cpp
division.cpp
multiplication.cpp
subtraction.cpp)
```

I know three is a way like this can solve the problem:

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
 
add_executable(calculator ${SOURCES})
```

but it will add all the source files to one target, this is not a good idea. I just want to get the source files that the target depends on. In particular, if one target depends on many libraries, it is not an easy task to add all relevant dependencies to each target, so I want to ask if there is a better way to simplify it.

Comment: A target has [SOURCES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/SOURCES.html) property which contains the list of all source files for that target. You may add sources for the target at any time (in any `CMakeLists.txt`) by using [target_sources](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html) command.

Comment: Imho splitting the logic of the executable into libs + executable in this case is questionable at best. If you want to use libs, they should be properly set up including seperate folders for public headers. Also in this case I'd strongly recommend making the libs static explicitly. The fact that it "doesn't look good" shouldn't be an excuse to separate the logic into libraries in a weird way. Rather than doing this try to make the `CMakeLists.txt` file better, e.g. by storing targets into different variables, ect.